# .htaccess file wont redirect to /public folder (laravel issue)

Tags: apache, laravel, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have folder `/var/www/html/project/himp` and there is my laravel installation.
In `/var/www/html/project` is my landing page index.html and some css files.

Inside `/himp` folder I have .htaccess:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

also in `/himp/public` folder I have also .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now when I go to the **domain.com/himp/public** I get Laravel installation and startup screen but when I go to the **domain.com/himp** I get just folder views, so there is no redirection to public folder ...

Why? What can be a problem here? Please help.

Comment: Can't you just point the domain to that folder without the need of redirection etc?

Comment: I cant becouse I have landing page in domain.com and laravel app need to access in domain.com/himp

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the pattern in [`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#what_is_matched) (see "What is matched?"), the variable `REQUEST_URI` contains the *full* path, including `/himp`. So the condition should be either

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public
```

without a beginning of string anchor `^`, or you must include the full path

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/himp/public
```

Comment: no, dont work... can we please go to the chat so I can show you url

Comment: I just looked, but I cannot invite you into chat. So what happens, what does "dont work" mean? When I setup my test system with the given .htaccess files and then enter `example.com/himp`, Apache rewrites to `/himp/public/index.php` as it should.